# Submit Array with Cakephp Form Helper

Tags: arrays, forms, cakephp, submit, helper

I have the below formhelper code where $spot is an array of variables:

```
   echo $form->create('Spot', array('controller' => 'spots', 'action' => 'view'));
                    echo $form->hidden('spotdata', array('value' => $spot));
                    echo $form->end('View');
```

When I print_r($this->data) in my controller, the spotdata is empty.  Can the formhelper accept values that are arrays?  Is there any way to do this? Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are sending the data to a view. It's more idiomatic to just send the ID to the view, and the data can be reloaded from the database. In which case a link would be enough:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View', 
    array('controller' => 'spots', 'action' => 'view', $spot['Spot']['id']));
```

If you are trying to keep the state between pages you may find it easier and more secure to use the `SessionComponent` to do this (never trust data sent back from the client). In your controller method, this is as easy as:

```
$this->Session->write('Spot.spotData', $spot);
```

and

```
$spot = $this->Session->read('Spot.spotData');
```

to read back the data.

Answer (score 1):

No, since it echoes an HTML input tag.  The value has to be a string or something that can be cast as a string.  View your HTML source.

Comment: k thanks. i just looped through and echo'd each key => value as a hidden input

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the array and echo'ing each key, you can also [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and place it in a single hidden input. Afterwards you can [deserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it